# Javascript Viewport object looping

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, canvas, viewport

i have a viewport which contains a bunch of "blocks" (9 in total). every "block" got a bunch of "object" arrays and another "object" array. each "object" contains a "shape" (its really difficult to explain this sorry)

it looks like that.
[http://imgur.com/BXCtpxx](https://imgur.com/BXCtpxx)

is there a way to make a loop going through every "Shape" in every block which returns me the "shape" content?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var flatten = []

vp.blocks.forEach(function(block){
  block.objects.forEach(function(object){
    object.objects.forEach(function(object){
      flatten.push(object.shape)
    })
})
```